# Unrelated template parse error in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am developing a simple Angular 6 application. At a certain point a 'Template parse error' appeared, literally out of nowhere: "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. I don't use any template or ng-template in my code. Anybody with an idea?

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
"let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="rows" [ERROR ->]let-rowz="$implicit" let-index="index">
      <tr *ngIf="!(datePicker.onlyCurrentMonth && rowz[0].sec"): ng:///DatepickerModule/DayPickerComponent.html@38:37
"let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="rows" let-rowz="$implicit" [ERROR ->]let-index="index">
      <tr *ngIf="!(datePicker.onlyCurrentMonth && rowz[0].secondary && rowz[6].sec"): ng:///DatepickerModule/DayPickerComponent.html@38:58
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:19495)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25041)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25028)
    at compiler.js:24971
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24971)
    at compiler.js:24881
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2538)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24880)
```

Comment: please show the code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong you are using an *ngFor and you are trying to get the index and if that's the case try following the below example.

```
<div *ngFor="let element of array; let $index = index">{{$index}}</div>
```

And I think what you are doing is `let-index = index;`, which I concluded from the error trace you have uploaded. You are using an - between let and index.